How to fix “Bottom overflowed by 359 pixels” when keyboard is opened in Flutter?
I’m using a Container with a fixed height of 478 pixels that contains a TextField. When the keyboard is opened, I get a “Bottom overflowed by 359 pixels” error. Here is my code:
Container(
  height: 478,
  child:  ListView.builder(
                                physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                itemCount: list.length,
                           TextField(controller:notesController,),
)

Whenever I tried to use keyboard i'm getting “Bottom overflowed by 359 pixels”,
I have used resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, but this doesn't worked.
How can I fix this issue?

Wrap it in SingleChildScrollView.

it doesn't worked,

have you tried to wrap the entire scaffold with SingleChildScrollView.

I don't want complete screen should scroll only listviewbuilder has scrollable,

@MoonPrincess Can you share your full screen code?

In your Scaffold use:
resizeToAvoidBottomInset = false.

It will prevent keyboard to push your content while it's open.

You can add Padding to your container like this
Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
    bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
  ),
    child: Container(
       height: 478,
       child: TextField(controller:notesController,),
      ),
)

And set isScrollControlled property to true in your showModalBottomSheet function.

SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  height: 478,
                  child: TextField(controller:notesController,),
                ),
              )


Wrap it with SingleChildScrollView


Its doesn't worked
